# Why do I get a conflict between Lotus Notes and Skype?

Tags: lotus-notes, skype, lotusscript

I have form in which a LotusScript routine ends with uidoc.Refresh.

When that happens, Lotus Notes hangs.

Looking at the Wait Chain in Task Manager show that nlnotes.exe is waiting for Skype.exe. If I kill Skype from there, Notes starts working again.  Also, if I Quit Skype via the UI, Notes starts working again.

We have no code that has any interaction between Skype and Notes, so this is really annoying.

I did read somewhere about Skype hogging Ports 80 and 443, and thought that might be the problem, but I have disabled that in the Connections section of the Advanced Options of Skype and it has not helped.

I am using Skype Version 7.26.80.101 and IBM Notes 9.01 FP6.

Any suggestions?

Comment: The only solution for that is changing one of the ports not disabling.

Comment: What happens if you (a) press F9 to refresh the form, and (b) run the same script on a form with no computed fields or validation formulas?

Comment: @RichardSchwartz, a) the same, b) I don't know yet, I've had 10 different issues to deal with today.  I'll try to investigate further tomorrow.

Comment: Sounds like you've got something in a field formula that's causing the problem. An @URLOpen, perhaps.

Comment: Actually, I'm pretty sure now that it's an OLE object that's opening the wrong application.